# Accessing variable inside object property

Tags: javascript, object, scope

So I encountered a problem. I have this object called `myTree`. And that object has properties. One of the properties contains a method like this:

```
prep: function (variable) {
    /* some code */
}
```

In that method there is an array `myarray` and I want to know, whether it is possible to access the content of that array, and if it is, how I would do that.

I've made a demo on jsFiddle, and in the end of the JavaScript window you can see that I'm alerting the object `prep` in which `myarray` is contained.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wp7Xh/1/

Comment: in your code example I noticed that you wrapped functions in parentheses, like property : (function() {...})
Can you please construe for what reason that is?

Comment: @caligula http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053842/advanced-javascript-why-is-this-function-wrapped-in-parentheses

Comment: but you don't call these functions (in your jsfiddle example), you don't use  (function() {...})(), you simply warp them but do not call
(function() {...}). is there any reason for that which I don't know or is this the error (at least redundant thing)?

Comment: @caligula I'm calling this object methods on other places. And it's not an error. I just want to access some variables withing these functions, and with that I have a problem. Everything else is working just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access object properties within object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789141/access-object-properties-within-object)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript variables are function-scoped. It is not possible to access variables belonging to an inner scope (i.e. *"function"*) from an outer scope.

If you want that kind of access, you must make the respective variable part of the outer scope.

```
var myTree = function() {
  var myarray = [];

  this.prep = function (variable) {
    myarray.push(variable);
  };
}
```

In your scenario, where you have nested objects, it's quite similar:

```
var myTree = {
  myarray: [],
  prep: function (variable) {
    this.myarray.push(variable);
  }
}
```

The only difference is the use of the `this` keyword.

When you define an object via the *object literal* syntax (`obj = {prop: value}`) instead of via a constructor (`function Obj(value) { this.prop = value; }; obj = new Obj(value);`), then all defined properties will be "public" by default.

When you call a function on that object, `this` will point to the respective object instance.

Accessing an "inner scope" variable from outside is still impossible. There's no way around that.

Generally speaking: You can access properties of the objects you construct. You can never access function local variables (except from the inside of nested functions).

Comment: The first example contains a syntax error, looks like you meant to convert an object literal to a function but forgot `function ()` in the first line of code.