# Converting JS script for server-side/PhantomJS using require()

Tags: javascript, requirejs, packaging, phantomjs

Trying to use [resemble.js](http://huddle.github.com/Resemble.js/) within a server-side PhantomJS script is throwing undefined errors and no amount of logging will penetrate past {object Object}.  Patterning after the phantom/examples/universe.js file, I tried turning the [original resemble.js file](https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js/blob/master/resemble.js):

```
(function (_this) {
  _this['resemble'] = function (fileData) {
    ...
  }
}(this));
```

into

```
exports.create = function () {
  (function (_this) {
    _this['resemble'] = function (fileData) {
      ...
    }
  }(this));
};
```

as well as

```
exports.create = function () {
  resemble = function (fileData) {
    ...
  }
};
```

First off, what the hell does that dangling `(this)` do?  Secondly, how can I log that object?  Finally, what is the proper way of wrapping up that file?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really, I was loading Casper as a module so that I could directly access Phantom objects. I was also hoping to use a batching system, so I could decouple the analysis from the actual benchmarking (trying to get a visual benchmark on ATF load times).

Comment: It also looks like I must now use a non-phantom controller, as I can't switch proxies after loading the phantom test.

Comment: Try https://github.com/kpdecker/node-resemble
Node port of Resemble.js.

Answer (score 1):

For running resemble from within phantomJS, check out https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS. Clone and you are immediately up and running. Replace phantomjs.exe with the correct binary for your system if you aren't on windows.

You haven't quite pasted the `(this)` at the end correctly. Anyways, it's an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). The first argument of the function, `_this` is just a scoped copy of the `(this)` at the end.

You can log it simply by dumping `_this` within the function body or by logging `this` outside of the function body.

Also see [What is this construct in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript) and [Advanced Javascript: Why is this function wrapped in parentheses? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053842/advanced-javascript-why-is-this-function-wrapped-in-parentheses/9055017#9055017)

Comment: (This) will help you identify current instance, where the function is called.

Comment: I was hoping to do my analysis out of band, using a batch system.  I'll take a look, however.

Comment: **Other answers would be appreciated, but the 100 goes to Ryan (unless he tells me to give it to someone else, as you DO have a lot of internet points already :D ), I just forgot to award the 50 point answer in time :/ **