# In JavaScript, Why function expression needs to be in bracket for calling the function

Tags: javascript, function, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

I tried calling

```
function(v){alert(""+v);}(4);
```

But warning came out

```
function statement requires a name
```

When I called using name

```
function fname(v){alert(""+v);}(4);
```

Nothing happened
But when I called using brackets,

```
(function(v){alert(""+v);})(4);
and
(function fname(v){alert(""+v);})(4);
```

Both showed alert on screen.
Why did this all happened?

Comment: Although the question title talks about a plus sign rather than parentheses, the answers there answer this question (which is the dupe test on SO). Hope that helps.

Comment: [Why are parentheses require around JavaScript IIFE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910216/why-are-parentheses-require-around-javascript-iife)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Both function expression and function declaration starts with function keyword. Why would parser expect it to be declaration?

Comment: No, expressions here start with a `(` or with a `+` or a `!`, etc.

Comment: @RahulJain: Because it's where a statement is expected rather than an expression, and they had to make a decision about what `function` meant there, and that's what they decided. E.g., it's arbitrary. Even though JavaScript has *ExpressionStatement* (you can use an expression as a statement), you can't use a *FunctionExpression* as a statement, just because it's ambiguous. So (as the linked question's answers say), we have to do something to put the parser in a state where it's expecting *only* an expression, not a statement. `(` does that, as does `+`, ...

Comment: @MinusFour: Rahul's speaking of the general case: A function expression does indeed start with `function`, just like a function declaration does. So it's context that tells the parser which production it should treat it as.

Comment: Should I delete this question as it is marked duplicate?