# In preparing for 70-480 Microsoft exam, I need help understanding why an añswer is Correct

Tags: javascript, html

With the code below, customer.name is undefined. Can someone help me understand why and what is going on with the code?

```
    var customer = function () {
     var name = "Contoso";
     return {
          getName: function () {
                return name;
          },
          setName: function (newName) {
                name = newName;
          }
     };
}();
alert (customer.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost [a classic JS module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) - [an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053842/advanced-javascript-why-is-this-function-wrapped-in-parentheses) that returns an object but which also allows for variable privacy.

I said *almost* because a module pattern generally looks like this.

```
var customer = (function () {
  //
})();
```

The following line scopes a string as a local variable and applies it to `name`. It cannot be accessed outside of the IIFE *because* of its scope.

```
var name = "Contoso";
```

Because the function is immediately invoked it returns this object an applies it to `customer`. One method returns the value of `name`, the other updates it.

```
return {
  getName: function () { return name; },
  setName: function (newName) { name = newName; }
};
```

But, because `name` is "private" to the IIFE (module), `customer.name` returns `undefined`.

To get the name use the method on the returned object `customer.getName()`.

To set a new name use the other method `customer.setName('Bob')`.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jao5bgrf/1/)

Both these methods have access to the private variable `name` [due to a very important concept know as **function closure**](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36) whereby a function can hang on to ("closes around") its outer lexical environment - useful in this situation, and things like event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

When `customer.name` is called, javascript finds that `customer` is evaluated to this:

```
function () {
 var name = "Contoso";
 return {
      getName: function () {
            return name;
      },
      setName: function (newName) {
            name = newName;
      }
 };
```

The variable `name` within this function, belongs to the function's memory, or local scope, and is not available anywhere outside of the function. `name` was declared as ***var name*** not as ***this.name***, so it isn't made avaliable *through* the function, only *to* the function.

So inside the function, we can say `name = blah`, but outisde the function we can not. We have to call a function within the function to access it. That's what we have `getName` and `setName` for. They are within the function which represents `customer` and therefore have access to the local variable `name`.

We could either declare `name` with **this.name** within the function, or just change the way we are trying to access customer.name like so:

```
alert( customer.getName() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable customer is undefined, as it outside the scope of the function, at line `alert(customer.name);`