# JavaScript completely wrapping ()?

Tags: javascript

Why () is used to cover a function declaration like this:
(function{};)
Is this standard?
What is the use of this statement

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911/what-is-the-purpose-of-wrapping-whole-javascript-files-in-anonymous-functions-li/2421949#2421949

Comment: This also might provide you with some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053842/advanced-javascript-why-is-this-function-wrapped-in-parentheses