# How to call the function from browser console?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to call the function from browser console for testing purpose ?

test is working as expected , but test2 is not working

```
function test() {
  alert(0);
}
(function(e, t) {
  var test2 = (function() {
    alert(2)
  })
})
```

**Calling for browser console**

```
test() // its working

test2() // Uncaught ReferenceError: test2 is not defined
```

Comment: `test2` is not visible - it cannot be called.

Comment: Then How to access test2 ? any possible ?

Comment: thought it was an IIFE but see now it isn't.

Comment: @RandyCasburn this files comes from external source so I cannot edit , I need to confirm all functions working from console

Comment: Then it cannot be done.

Comment: @Teemu — That isn't true

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic problems here:

## `test2` never exists

`test2` is defined inside a function which is never called, so it is never defined.

The code would have to actually call the anonymous function it is inside.

However, assuming that is a side effect of you truncating the code for this question and in your real case that anonymous function does get called:

## `test2` isn't a global

So in order to access it, you need to be in the right scope.

The only way to do that for the console would be to:

1. open up the *sources* tab of the browser's developer tools
2. add a breakpoint inside the anonymous function
3. run the code until your reach the breakpoint
4. **then** use the console to access `test2` which is now in scope.

Note that given the structure of that code you might have to put the breakpoint before `test2` has a value assigned to it and then step through the code until after it is defined.

Comment: File is comes from external source and that is minified version thats why code look like that way

Comment: https://stag-webviewjs.gosite.run/setFont.min.js this is the actual file

Answer (score 0):

Since your `test2` var is a function on it's own, no need to wrap them in `()`.

Copy/paste this into browser console to check;

```
var test2 = (function() {
    alert(2)
});
test2();
```

[Advanced JavaScript: Why is this function wrapped in parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053842/advanced-javascript-why-is-this-function-wrapped-in-parentheses)

---

Should you really want those parentheses, you can call the existing function like so;

```js
(function(e, t) {
  var test2 = (function() {
    alert(2)
  });
  test2(); // <-- Run function
})()
//^^ Extra parentheses to instantly run wrapper function
```

Comment: actually that file is come from external source so I cannot edit

Comment: If you can only copy/paste the code, there's no way to run `test2`.